# couldnt compile mysql procedure for cursors

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the below procedure to update a table but i could not compile the procedure.

```
CREATE
    PROCEDURE `propmanage2016`.`test`()
    DECLARE CURSOR cur1 FOR
         SELECT unit_id, unit_code FROM t_units WHERE unit_projectid = 1;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE a INT;
    DECLARE b VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    BEGIN
        OPEN cur1;    
        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO  b , a ;       
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            UPDATE t_owner_resident SET or_unit = a WHERE unit_name = b;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur1;
    END;
```

please give some help

Comment: What do you mean by "could not compile the procedure"? Stored procedures don't need to be compiled.

Comment: Do you mean you're getting an error when you try to create the procedure? What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can't do it like this without the stored procedure?

```
   UPDATE t_owner_resident ow INNER JOIN t_units t set ow.unit_name = t.unit_code 
   WHERE o.unit_name = t.unit_id and t.unit_projectid = 1
```

Note: I think a,b is mixed up in your SP, so please excuse if i've got the column names slightly mixed up too

Comment: Please use ANSI JOIN syntax in your answers, we don't want to teach bad habits.

Comment: Good point @Barmar it's a bad habit I myself aquired years ago from the mysql manual itself (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.htmlv) years ago and haven't been able to kick yet.

Comment: I understand. I haven't been able to get my boss to kick it, either.