# SQL Error: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE PROCEDURE KC_update_pricing()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE u_sku VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE u_product_size VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE u_product_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE u_chargeble_area DECIMAL DEFAULT 0.0;
    DECLARE u_user_id VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE u_last_update DATE;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR

      SELECT
        sku,
        product_size,
        product_name,
        chargeble_area,
        user_id,
        last_update
      FROM kcproduct_test_load
      WHERE last_update >= (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(max(last_update), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d-%m-%Y')
                            FROM kcpricing_test_load);
    OPEN Cur1;
    LOOP
      FETCH cur1
      INTO u_sku, u_product_size, u_product_name, u_chargeble_area, u_user_id, u_last_update;

      IF (u_product_size = 'S')
      THEN
        SET u_shipping = 99;
      ELSEIF (u_product_size = 'M')
        THEN
          SET u_shipping = 149;
      ELSEIF (u_product_size = 'L')
        THEN
          SET u_shipping = 199;
      ELSEIF (u_product_size = 'XS')
        THEN
          SET u_shipping = 99;
      ELSEIF (u_product_size = 'XXS')
        THEN
          SET u_shipping = 69;
      ELSE
        SET u_shipping = 199;
      END IF;

      UPDATE kcpricing_test_load
      SET base_price = (u_chargeble_area * 150)
      WHERE sku = u_SKU;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: Procedure is compiled but not fetching any row where as select in cursor definition will fetch 1 roq when executed separately.

Comment: you don't need a stored procedure for this. What you need is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41035791/267540

Comment: Rakesh, welcome to SO.  Next time, please instead off adding an additional new comment to your question, just place that as direct edit into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

have an exception command in the cursor some thing like below :

Exception
When NO_DATA_FOUND then 
 continue
end;

it will help to avoid no data found error.